# Flask and PhantomJS, Evaluate internal URL

Tags: python, flask, phantomjs

I'm need to evaluate a internal url from within Flask (0.10.1) using PhantomJS (1.9.8). If I substitute `http://www.google.com` for the url it correctly evaluates. If I serve the html up on another IP it correctly evaluates. When I try to use a internal URL the page hangs and I receive `502 Bad Gateway`.  I've been struggling with this for weeks. It obviously has something to do with calling the internal url inside the Flask app, but I don't know how to get around this. Any help is much appreciated.

**controllers.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
phantomjs = os.path.expanduser('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
log = os.path.expanduser('/home/www/tmp/ghostdriver.log')

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(phantomjs, service_log_path=log)
driver.get('http://localhost/calendar')
html = driver.page_source

return render_template('{{html}}.html', html=html)
```

**ghostdriver.log**

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2016-01-07T19:40:33.072Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 43105
[INFO  - 2016-01-07T19:40:33.927Z] Session [848c6530-b576-11e5-86dc-813b8c0d63bb] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2016-01-07T19:40:33.927Z] Session [848c6530-b576-11e5-86dc-813b8c0d63bb] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2016-01-07T19:40:33.927Z] Session [848c6530-b576-11e5-86dc-813b8c0d63bb] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.8","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.1.0","platform":"linux-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2016-01-07T19:40:33.927Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 848c6530-b576-11e5-86dc-813b8c0d63bb
[ERROR - 2016-01-07T19:41:03.375Z] Session [848c6530-b576-11e5-86dc-813b8c0d63bb] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.update.bind(this)')
[ERROR - 2016-01-07T19:41:03.375Z] Session [848c6530-b576-11e5-86dc-813b8c0d63bb] - page.onError - stack:
  Headroom (http://localhost/static/js/headroom/headroom.js:117)
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost/static/js/headroom/jQuery.headroom.js:26)
  (anonymous function) (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
  (anonymous function) (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost/static/js/headroom/jQuery.headroom.js:33)
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost/static/js/custom.js:184)
  (anonymous function) (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
  (anonymous function) (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
  (anonymous function) (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
  I (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js:2)
```

**nginx error.log**

```
2016/01/07 14:41:02 [error] 924#0: *39 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: , request: "POST /taper/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/taper/", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/taper/"
```

Comment: and if you try `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`?

Comment: @Monkpit same result

Comment: can you open `http://localhost/calendar` on any browser (namely, not a headless one)?; does the page render ok? this will test if phantomjs is the problem. Also, can you try explicitly setting the port on your get request?